# Hatcher A.1 , difficulty in understanding a certain step

Tags: general-topology, geometry, algebraic-topology, proof-explanation

In hatcher (algebraic topology) proposition A.1 page 520 in the appendix section, I don't see why we have $\phi_{\alpha}^{-1}(S)$ necessarily closed in $\partial D_{\alpha}^n$, once we have this I can see why $$\Phi_{\alpha}^{-1}(S)$$ contains at most one more point and is thus closed, but I struggle to understand the first part.

Here is the proposition for reference:

[image: Algebraic Topology - Hatcher , Page 520]

Comment: Is $\phi_\alpha$ the edge-gluing map and $\Phi_\alpha$ the cell map of cell $\alpha$?

Comment: Sorry, so hatcher has defined $\Phi_{\alpha}$ as the composition $D_{\alpha}^n \hookrightarrow X^{n-1} \coprod \coprod_{\alpha} D_{\alpha}^n \rightarrow X^n \hookrightarrow X$ where the first arrow is the canonical inclusion, the second arrow is the quotient map and the third arrow the canonical inclusion. Therefore I think $\phi_{\alpha}$ is the same map restricted to the boundary (although this was only  defined in hatcher as a map $\partial{D_{\alpha}^n} \rightarrow X^{n-1}$ when constructing the $n$-skeleton)

Comment: Oh, I think I resolved my confusion, the map hatcher is talking about is just the edge gluing map composed with the inclusion $X^{n-1} \hookrightarrow X$, and its preimage of $S$ is closed because $S \cap X^{n-1}$ is closed and it is continuous.

Comment: @porridgemathematics Then you should write an answer to your own question.

Comment: Yes! I will do so soon :)

Answer (score 2):

The map given by the attaching map $\partial D_{\alpha}^n \rightarrow X^{n-1}$ composed with the inclusion $X^{n-1} \hookrightarrow X$ is equal to the map $\Phi_{\alpha}$ restricted to $\partial D_{\alpha}^n$. Therefore this maps preimage on the set $S$ is necessarily closed, as we assumed that $S \cap X^{n-1}$ is closed inductively.